# ¿Como guardar el ultimo elemento de un combobox dinamico en c#?

Tags: c#

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en el cual guardo todos mis elementos en un combobox ya que `no sé muy bien hacerlo  con listas o diccionarios`.

La cosa es que el combobox ira agregando elementos y aumentando de tamaño. El problema esque necesito seleccionar el ultimo elemento cada vez que ocurra un determinado evento.

Bueno agrego los elementos de la siguiente manera y al mismo tiempo cito que el combobox ira aumentando de tamaño a medida que el programa este funcionando:

```
private void EntityLoad(DataInterceptedEventArgs obj){
    var entities = HEntity.Parse(obj.Packet);
    foreach(var entity in entities){
        Index = entity.Index;
        Id = entity.Id;
        Profile = entity.FigureId;
        playerList.Items.Add(entity.Index + "," + entity.Id + "," + entity.FigureId);
        //MessageBox.Show("figure id: "+ entity.FigureId +"el id del buny" + entity.Id + "buny index:" + entity.Index+ ", position: "+ entity.Tile.X + "," + entity.Tile.Y + "," + entity.Tile.Z);

    }
}
```

Lo que quiero que cada vez ocurra lo cual para esto no es necesario que me ayudeis ya que se como hacerlo. Lo que quiero es que cada vez que ocurra ese evento el ultimo elemento de mi combobox. Entonces mi pregunta es:

Si tengo `un combobox que cambia de tamaño` puedo `sacar el ultimo elemento` cada vez que se lance mi evento.

Segundo es más recomendable usar `un diccionario o lista para guardar mis elementos`.

`El combobox será dinamico` pero yo le indicaré el momento solamente que necesitaré saber como sacar el ultimo elemento `sabiendo que variará de tamaño`.

Aqui teneis una captura del combobox que ira aumentando a medida que se ejecute mi programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Correción: Mi objetivo es coger el ultimo elemento de mi combobox, guardarlo y si fuese posible hacer un split como ejemplo práctico que me ayudaría bastante**

Ejemplo.

Combobox:

```
"hola,dos,tres"
"1,dos,tres"
"2,dos,tres"
```

Obtendré:

```
Obtener el ultimo elemento.
lo guardaré.
y haré un split para guardar los elementos por separado: 
int i=2
string dos =  "dos"
string tres =  "tr"
```

Comment: combobox.Items.Count - 1  <-- Has intentado con esto?

Comment: Se ha cambiado varias veces el contenido; sugiero des una leida de nuevo a fin de establecer bien cual es el apoyo que requieres.

Comment: he corregido la descripción y el titulo os habreis dado cuenta que cambio anteriormente, si fuera posible revisar estas modificaciones, disculpar las molestias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin importar si es dinamico o no:

```
var ultimo = combobox.items.count - 1;
```

Para seleccionarlo

```
combobox.selectedindex = ultimo;
```

`combobox.items.count` <-- siempre traerá el número de elementos, -1 para obtener le ultimo index.

Y cada vez que re dimensiones tu combo tendrias que tomar ese valor que va estar cambiando.

Para tomar el valor

- Seleccionándolo y tomando el `selected`

  ```
   var ultimo = combobox.items.count - 1;
   combobox.selectedindex = ultimo;  //<-- con esto lo dejas seleccionado
   var valor = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
  ```
- Directo con el indice

  ```
   var ultimo = combobox.items.count - 1;
   var valor = combobox.items[ultimo].Value;  //No estoy segura de la sintaxis
  ```

Ya que tengas el valor:

```
var datos = valor.Split(',');
if(datos.length > 2){
   int i=datos[0];
   string dos =  datos[1];
   string tres =  datos[2];
}
```

Algo así, espero que mis ejemplos te puedan ayudar, Saludos... y no es ninguna molestia por cierto.

Comment: combobox.items.count no es el último; es cuanto elementos existen.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas corregido gracias :-)

Comment: @jeronimourtado Te refieres a guardar el valor que contiene el elemento?

Comment: lo unico asi que veo a un var no le puedes hacer un split creo, por lo demás me ayudo bastante gracias!

Comment: lo que si se podría hacer es convertir valor a string.                            
        string arr = Convert.ToString(valor); y luego hacer el split y guardarlo en un array. teniendo en cuenta que para los enteros con un parse uno va sobrado int i = int.Parse(arr);

Comment: entendido @jeronimourtado  :-)  Gracias